# Input field ignores a value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a problem with an input field that ignores the value of the formControl `amount`.

```html
@for (service of dataSource; track dataSource; let index = $index) {
          <table mat-table *ngIf="dataSource && dataSource[index]" [dataSource]="dataSource[index]" formArrayName="services">
            <!-- more code -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="amount">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Amount</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
                {{ element.amount }} <!-- Returns 1 -->
                <mat-form-field *ngIf="element.amount">
                  <mat-label>Amount</mat-label>
                  <input matInput placeholder="Enter Amount" formControlName="amount">
                </mat-form-field>

              </td>
            </ng-container>
           <!-- more code -->
          </table>
        }
```

When I debug my code, I see that my form contains the formControl `amount` and it has a value. Also, `{{ element.amount }}` outputs a number.

This is how I set its value:

```js
private createForm(quotationView: QuotationView): void {
  const serviceFormGroup = this._formBuilder.array<FormGroup>([]);

  quotationView.services.forEach((service: Service) => {
    console.log(service.defaultAmount); // Returns 1
    const defaultAmount = service.defaultAmount;
    const groupOfServices = this._formBuilder.group({
      serviceIsSelected: (service.typeOfService !== 'optional'),
      amount: new FormControl({ value: service.defaultAmount, disabled: false }, Validators.required),
      ...service
    });
    serviceFormGroup.push(groupOfServices);
  });
```

This bug is confusing me, because `console.log(service.defaultAmount)` returns `1`, but the input field perceives it as `null`. I know this, because if I set the value to `service.defaultAmount + '-TEST'`, then the value of the input field is `null-TEST`. I can also set the value to any number or any string, and I see that value in the input field. How comes that any value works, but not the value of `service.defaultAmount`?

### Update

I have figured out that it must be an async issue since when data is static, it works fine. This is how I receive the data from API and send it to `createForm()`:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this._activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params): void => {
    // Mark page as seen
    this._quotationViewService.markQuotationAsSeen(params['id']);
    // Receive quotation data
    this._quotationViewService.getQuotation(params['id']).subscribe((quotation: QuotationView): void => {
      this.createForm(quotation);
      this.quotation = this.form.value;
      this.dataSource = this.groupServices(this.form.get('services')?.value);
    })
  });
}

private groupServices(services: QuotationView['services']): Service[][] {
  return services.reduce((acc: Service[][], obj: Service) => {
    const existingGroup: Service[] | undefined = acc.find((group: Service[]): boolean => group[0].sectionSequence === obj.sectionSequence);
    if (existingGroup) {
      existingGroup.push(obj);
    } else {
      acc.push([obj]);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the destructuring you are doing.

If you look at your code, suppose `service` property has `amount` property defined already. Then by the logic of destructuring the latest value is taken, so your form control will get overridden by the property of service.

To fix this issue, please destructure the service first then apply the form controls. This might be the issue!

```
private createForm(quotationView: QuotationView): void {
  const serviceFormGroup = this._formBuilder.array<FormGroup>([]);

  quotationView.services.forEach((service: Service) => {
    console.log(service.defaultAmount); // Returns 1
    const defaultAmount = service.defaultAmount;
    const groupOfServices = this._formBuilder.group({
      ...service, //                                        <- changed here!
      serviceIsSelected: (service.typeOfService !== 'optional'),
      amount: new FormControl({ value: service.defaultAmount, disabled: false }, Validators.required),
    });
    serviceFormGroup.push(groupOfServices);
  });
  ...
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code but that doesn't work. `service` has not a `amount` property. That is why I want to add it.

Comment: @xRay is it possible to provide a minimal stackblitz with the issue replicated?

Comment: Unfortunately, on Stackblitz I can use static data only and there it works fine.  My problem must be because of async. Please see my updated question.

Comment: @xRay we can use `rxjs` `delay` operator to simulate and API call like `of([]).pipe(delay(3000))`, plz try this and share back the stackblitz!

Answer (score 0):

The "easy way to manange a FormArray using a mat table is that the datasource was the formArray.controls

So,we can use some like

```
formArray = new FormArray(
    ELEMENT_DATA.map(
      (x) =>
        new FormGroup({
          position: new FormControl(x.position),
          name: new FormControl(x.name),
          weight: new FormControl(x.weight),
          symbol: new FormControl(x.symbol),
        })
    )
  );
//see that we indicate that the datasource elements will be formGroups
dataSource=this.formArray.controls.map(x=>x as FormGroup);
```

Now, we can use the table like

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" >

  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [formGroup]="element"> 
        <input formControlName='weight'/>
   </td>
</ng-container>

</table>
```

See that we can also use ngModel to change the value of the form array in the way

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
       <input [ngModel]="element.get('name').value"
              (ngModelChange)="element.get('name').setValue($event)"/>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

And the dataSource can be simply the formArray.controls

```
dataSource=this.formArray.controls.map(x=>x as FormGroup);
```

A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-embafu?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Findex.html)